# Sending a string from ajax to controller resulting with null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown that iterates over an enum list, when chosen it sends the enum as a string.(as 'this')

then I get the value of that object to get the string value.

here is how it looks like,

the select dropdown:

```
<select id="userServicesDropDownAuth" class="browser-default custom-select" 
  asp-for="Service" onchange="validateUserAuth(this, '@username', '@password')">
    @{
        <option style="display:none"></option>
        foreach (var item in services)
        {
            <option>@item.ToString()</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

The ajax call:

```js
var service = service.value;
$.ajax({
    url: '/Actions/CheckServiceValidation',
    method: 'POST',
    data: service ,
    dataType: 'text',
    contentType :'text',
    success: function (data) {
```

and finally the controller method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public bool CheckServiceValidation(string service)
{
  
    var session = SessionManager.GetSession(service);
    if (session== service)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

The string recieved in the controller method is null, when I change it from string to a Service object (enum) it always returns the first index.

the enum class:

```cs
public enum Service : int
{
    Badoo = 0,
    Tinder = 1,
    Grinder = 2,
    OkCupid = 3
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

the ajax event receiving the service
[image]

even if I pick index 3 from the dropdown, the service that is passed to the controller is always 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to give the data property the same name as the one inside the controller.

```
 var service = service.options[service.selectedIndex].text;
$.ajax({
    url: '/Actions/CheckServiceValidation',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { 'service': service } ,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
```

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me it's always returning the first item of your drop-down. You add a first option with value:

```
<option style="display:none"></option>
```

You need to set you var to use the selected option of your drop-down list. Something like:

```
var service = Service.options[Service.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: I dont think thats the problem because the ajax event is recieving the service, editing main post with photo.